# XmlSerializer and XmlElement fields

Tags: c#, .net, xml, xml-serialization

I have an xml that looks like this:

```
<Config>
<A></A>
<Template><B/><C/></Template>
</Config>
```

and I would like to deserialize it in to get the `<Template><B/><C/></Template>` bit as a XmlElement or XmlNode. But when I try like this:

```
public class Config
{
     public string A;
     public XmlElement Template;
}
```

the Template is set to `<B/>` only. Any ideas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Decorate your Template member with an [XmlAnyElement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlanyelementattribute.aspx) attribute. That should do the trick.